# How to use Apache Flink DataSet python API with an IDE like e.g. PyCharm on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows-10, pycharm, apache-flink

all said in the Title:

How do I use the apache flink python API within an IDE like e.g. pycharm on Windows 10?

And no, I'm not going to use Java or Scala - and yes, I have googled, for hours and for a massive set of different keywords - I completely failed to see if there exists any kind of proper manual, serving an A to Z introduction in how to deploy an Flink environment.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run Flink python programs in the IDE. You have to start a cluster and submit the .py file using the pyflink.sh/pyflink.bat script as described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/batch/python.html#executing-plans).

Comment: thank you for your response. Good to know. I came up with that idea because you actually -can- just import the jar files from the lib folder of link in eclipse and stark prototyping your flink programs. I hoped that the same approach is possible in the Python setting.